# Weird while loop causes infinite loop

Tags: python, while-loop

This is a small code snippet which is causing my program to crash due to an infinite loop

```
while not stack.is_empty():
    if operators[stack.peek()] >= operators[character]:
        result += stack.pop()
```

where stack is a Stack object and operators is a dictionary.
The below code however does not cause an infinite loop

```
while not stack.is_empty() and operators[stack.peek()] >= operators[character]:
    result += stack.pop()
```

My question is: Aren't these code snippets basically the same thing ? Why is one causing an infinite loop while the other isn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one keeps looping through and peeking at the stack and checking whether a condition is true, but continuing. In the second one it cuts off after the condition is false

Comment: ...which means you could make them equivalent by adding an `else: break` in the first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
while not stack.is_empty():
    if operators[stack.peek()] >= operators[character]:
        result += stack.pop()
```

Here, the while loop runs until stack is empty and you pop only for `>=`, it leaves some elements in the stack for `<` condition. So in order for the stack to become empty, stack.size() == number of times `operators[stack.peek()] >= operators[character]` is `true`

---

```
while not stack.is_empty() and operators[stack.peek()] `>=` operators[character]:
    result += stack.pop()
```

Here, you are restricting the while loop by only allowing it to continue only when `>=` condition is statisfied along with stack not empty.